# PHP arrays, getting to loop index information

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Let me explain the array bellow:

1, 2 and 3 stand for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday.

13, 14, and 15 are the days of the month.

And 15:00 - 16:20 (..) are the hours the movies are going to be shown.

Meaning on Monday 13th from 3pm to 4:20pm you can watch “Batman”.

Also on Monday 13th from 6:10pm to 7:30pm you can watch “Misery”  … and so on.

```
$myarray
: array = 
  1: array = 
    13: array = 
      15:00 - 16:20: array = 
        Movie: string = Batman                 
      18:10 - 19:30: array = 
        Movie: string = Misery                 
  2: array = 
    14: array = 
      15:00 - 16:20: array = 
        Movie: string = The Avengers                
      16:20 - 17:50: array = 
        Movie: string = The Hours                 
  3: array = 
    15: array = 
      18:10 - 19:30: array = 
        Movie: string = Gladiator
```

Could you please help me to echo this array so you can see the info in it in the following format?:

```
Monday - 13
15:00 - 16:20 - Batman
18:10 - 19:30 - Misery
Tuesday – 14 
15:00 - 16:20 - The Avengers                
16:20 - 17:50 - The Hours
Wednesday – 15
8:10 - 19:30  -  Gladiator
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your array is not valid php format. Are `16:20 - 17:50` supposed to be a key? I.e. can you use `$myarray[1][13]['15:00 - 16:20']` to fetch `array("Movie"=>"Batman")` (I hope not!)? I am sorry, I don't understand the notation you are using.

Comment: Can you just add the exact array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making an assumption about the true layout of your array, the following will create a `$weekDays` array to map an integer and a day of the week (I define the keys so you can shift them at any time):

```
$weekDays = (1=>'Monday', 2=>'Tuesday', 3=>'Wednesday', 4=>'Thursday', 5=>'Friday', 6=>'Saturday', 7=>'Sunday');

// loop through each week-day in the array
foreach ($myarray as $weekDay => $dates) {
    // loop through each "movie date" in the current week-day block
    foreach ($dates as $monthDate => $movies) {
        // output the day-of-the-week and the date-of-the-month
        echo $weekDays[$weekDay] . ' - ' . $monthDate . '<br />';

        // loop through all of the movies for the current date-of-the-month
        foreach ($movies as $movieTime => $movie) {
            // output the movie's time and name
            echo $movieTime . ' - ' . $movie . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming the array in your example is really in the format:

```
$myarray = array(
    1 => array(
        13 => array(
            '15:00 - 16:20' => array(
                'Movie' => 'Batman'
            ),
            '18:10 - 19:30' => array(
                'Movie' => 'Misery'
            )
        ), // ... can repeat
    ), // ... can repeat
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code below : [See Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ss96s0)

```
$myarray = array(
    1 => array(
        13 => array(
            "15:00 - 16:20" => array(
                "Movie" => " Batman"
            ),
            "18:10 - 19:30" => array(
                "Movie" => " Misery"
            )
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        14 => array(
            "15:00 - 16:20" => array(
                "Movie" => " The Avengers "
            ),
            "16:20 - 17:50" => array(
                "Movie" => " The Hours "
            )
        )
    ),
    3 => array(
        15 => array(
            "18:10 - 19:30" => array(
                "Movie" => " Gladiator"
            )
        )
    )
);


$days = array(1 => 'Monday',2 => 'Tuesday',3 => 'Wednesday');

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
    foreach ( $value as $valueKey => $info ) {
        echo $days[$key], " - ", $valueKey, PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $info as $infoKey => $infoValue ) {
            echo $infoKey, " - ", $infoValue['Movie'], PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Monday - 13
15:00 - 16:20 -  Batman
18:10 - 19:30 -  Misery

Tuesday - 14
15:00 - 16:20 -  The Avengers 
16:20 - 17:50 -  The Hours 

Wednesday - 15
18:10 - 19:30 -  Gladiator
```